# Str Object is not Callable; Python Dictionary Loop Error

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, compiler-errors

```
#Dictionary Loop
d = {'key1':1,'key2':2}
for j in d:
    print(j, end=" ")
    print(j+" "+ str(d[j]))
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "E:/Learning/Python/ComparisonAndControlFlow/ForLoop.py", line 22, in 
>       print(j+" "+ str(d[j]))
>   TypeError: 'str' object is not callable*

Comment: can't reproduce the error from your code

Answer (score 1):

You assigned the variable name `str` to something elsewhere in your code, shadowing the [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) built-in. A minimal reproduction would be:

```
>>> str = 'something'
>>> try_string = str(5)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Python tries to use your assigned variable for the function call, resulting in your error. Find whatever you named `str` in your code, and rename it.

In general, **always make sure** you don't shadow [built-ins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) with your variable names, to prevent this from happening.